# Azure ml Studio Object Detection jupyter: Error to access the mltable for training the model

Tags: python, azure, azure-machine-learning-service, azureml-python-sdk, azure-ai

I am new with azure machine learning and I am still learnning. There is a file named annotations.jsonl saved in the subfolder "image-frames/dados_treinamento" inside the container "devplaifurnasdlfinal". The subfolder "image-frames" from the container "devplaifurnasdlfinal" was registered as a datastore in the azure machine learning studio under the name "image_frames". A code to training an object detection model was created and the training data must be passed to the code under the name "my_training_data_input". Below is the code:

```
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential
from azure.ai.ml import MLClient
from azure.ai.ml import automl
from azureml.core import Workspace
from azure.ai.ml.constants import AssetTypes
from azure.ai.ml import Input
from azureml.core.compute import AmlCompute, ComputeTarget
from azureml.exceptions import ComputeTargetException


# Load the workspace from the saved config file
ws = Workspace.from_config()

# Print the details of the workspace
print(f"Workspace name: {ws.name}")
print(f"Azure region: {ws.location}")
print(f"Resource group: {ws.resource_group}")
print(f"Subscription ID: {ws.subscription_id}")

# Define your workspace, datastore, and data paths
datastore_name = 'image_frames'
subscription_id = 'xxxx'
resource_group = 'yyyy'
workspace_name = 'zzzz'

credential = DefaultAzureCredential()
ml_client = None

try:
    ml_client = MLClient.from_config(credential)

except Exception as ex:
    print(ex)
    subscription_id = subscription_id
    resource_group = resource_group
    workspace = workspace_name

    ml_client = MLClient(credential, subscription_id, resource_group, workspace)


training_data_path = 'annotation_jsonl_path_from_container'
# the path is in the format https://devplaifurnasfinal.blob.core.windows.net/ima...


my_training_data_input = Input(
    type=AssetTypes.URI_FILE,
    path=training_data_path)

compute_name = "devplaipipe-run"  # Name of the compute target to retrieve

try:
    # Attempt to retrieve the existing compute target by name
    existing_compute_target = ComputeTarget(workspace=ws, name=compute_name)
    print("Found existing compute target:")
    print(f"Name: {existing_compute_target.name}")
    print(f"Type: {existing_compute_target.type}")

except ComputeTargetException:
    print("Creating a new compute target...")
    # Configure your compute target here
    provisioning_config = AmlCompute.provisioning_configuration(
        vm_size="Standard_NC6",
        idle_seconds_before_scaledown=120,
        min_nodes=0,
        max_nodes=4,)
    
    new_compute_target = ComputeTarget.create(ws, compute_name, provisioning_config)
    new_compute_target.wait_for_completion(show_output=True)
    print("New compute target created:")
    print(f"Name: {new_compute_target.name}")
    print(f"Type: {new_compute_target.type}")

    exp_name = "test-vscode-fine-tunning-objectdetection"

# Create the AutoML job with the related factory-function.
image_object_detection_job = automl.image_object_detection(
    compute=compute_name,
    experiment_name=exp_name,
    training_data=my_training_data_input,
    validation_data_size=0.25,
    target_column_name="label",
    primary_metric="mean_average_precision",
    tags={"my_custom_tag": "My custom value"},)

image_object_detection_job.set_limits(max_trials=5, max_concurrent_trials=2,)

# Submit the AutoML job
returned_job = ml_client.jobs.create_or_update(
    image_object_detection_job)  # submit the job to the backend

print(f"Created job: {returned_job}")

ml_client.jobs.stream(returned_job.name)
```

The annotations.jsonl is in the azure object detection annotation schema and this file can be acessed boot from the container and from datastore. I tried both ways and always a error arises. The code itself looks like is correct, printing infos it possible to see the correct workspace, gpu-cluster and so on. The error says that it cant access the mltable due to a permission access, but I don't know if that's the case, and if so, how can I fix this permission problem?
The error is below:

```
MLTable input is invalid. UserErrorException:
    Message: Encountered user error while fetching data from Dataset. Error: UserErrorException:
    Message: Failed to download mltable yaml with error: Getting permission error when trying to access MLTable,please make sure proper access is configured on storage: Dataflow visit error: ExecutionError(StreamError(PermissionDenied(None)))
    VisitError(ExecutionError(StreamError(PermissionDenied(None))))
=> Failed with execution error: error in streaming from input data sources
    ExecutionError(StreamError(PermissionDenied(None)))
    InnerException None
    ErrorResponse 
{
    "error": {
        "code": "UserError",
        "message": "Failed to download mltable yaml with error: Getting permission error when trying to access MLTable,please make sure proper access is configured on storage: Dataflow visit error: ExecutionError(StreamError(PermissionDenied(None)))\n\tVisitError(ExecutionError(StreamError(PermissionDenied(None))))\n=> Failed with execution error: error in streaming from input data sources\n\tExecutionError(StreamError(PermissionDenied(None)))"
    }
}
    InnerException UserErrorException:
    Message: Failed to download mltable yaml with error: Getting permission error when trying to access MLTable,please make sure proper access is configured on storage: Dataflow visit error: ExecutionError(StreamError(PermissionDenied(None)))
    VisitError(ExecutionError(StreamError(PermissionDenied(None))))
=> Failed with execution error: error in streaming from input data sources
    ExecutionError(StreamError(PermissionDenied(None)))
    InnerException None
    ErrorResponse 
{
    "error": {
        "code": "UserError",
        "message": "Failed to download mltable yaml with error: Getting permission error when trying to access MLTable,please make sure proper access is configured on storage: Dataflow visit error: ExecutionError(StreamError(PermissionDenied(None)))\n\tVisitError(ExecutionError(StreamError(PermissionDenied(None))))\n=> Failed with execution error: error in streaming from input data sources\n\tExecutionError(StreamError(PermissionDenied(None)))"
    }
}
    ErrorResponse 
{
    "error": {
        "code": "UserError",
        "message": "Encountered user error while fetching data from Dataset. Error: UserErrorException:\n\tMessage: Failed to download mltable yaml with error: Getting permission error when trying to access MLTable,please make sure proper access is configured on storage: Dataflow visit error: ExecutionError(StreamError(PermissionDenied(None)))\n\tVisitError(ExecutionError(StreamError(PermissionDenied(None))))\n=> Failed with execution error: error in streaming from input data sources\n\tExecutionError(StreamError(PermissionDenied(None)))\n\tInnerException None\n\tErrorResponse \n{\n    \"error\": {\n        \"code\": \"UserError\",\n        \"message\": \"Failed to download mltable yaml with error: Getting permission error when trying to access MLTable,please make sure proper access is configured on stora
```

Here is 3 imagens of the job, input training data, and a try to access the input data and finally an error on this try to explore the input data:
[image: job]
[image: input_data]
[image: access_data]
[image: explore_input_data_error]

It is really a permissiom problem, where (or what) I need to verify to correct this?

Answer (score 0):

I spent days with this exactly same error but in my case I was using the Azure API, had my App permissions set as "Owner" everywhere so I was expecting full access to blob storage, what was missing and giving me this error was the "Allow Public Access" configuration flag, which was set to disabled. So going to my Blob Storage Resource, configuration and then setting that flag to enabled allowed me to get rid of this error, [this](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-paas-blog/public-access-is-not-permitted-on-this-storage-account/ba-p/3521288) post goes in more details

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the contribution, but this option is already set to enable but the problem persist.

Comment: did you give machine learning compute "Owner permissions"? It is not a good practice but I set everything to owner just to make sure it has full access and then I tune it down, if you go to "Access Control" in your Blob Storage Resource add Roles the name of the created system managed identity will be in the format "/workspace-name/computes/compute-instance-name", same permission for the token that you may be using to connect to all this, I went quite insane giving owner permissions to everything when trying to pinpoint this issue